# REGEX Remove Space

Tags: regex

I want to creating regex to remove some matching string, the string is phone number

Example user input phone number like this:

`+jfalkjfkl saj f62 81 7876 asdadad30 asasda36`

then output will be like this:

`628178763036`

at the moment with my current regex `^[\+\sa-zA-Z]+` it can select the part `+jfalkjfkl saj f`

What is the regex so it also can select the space bewteen number?

e.g:

`62(select the space here)81`, `81(select the space here)7876`

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Can you clarify whether you want to retain the spaces between the digits or remove them? About half the answers remove them and half retain them.

Comment: @Bohemian i'm using PHP.

Comment: @StigBrautaset i want to remove the space, because phone number must not contains space :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know what language you plan on using this in, but you can replace this pattern:
 `[^\d]+`, with an empty string should accomplish this. It'll remove everything that's not a number.

Comment: But this will remove commas and any other characters too

Answer (score 1):

Using PCRE regexes, you should be able to simply remove anything matching `\D+`. Example:

```
echo "+jfalkjfkl saj f62 81 7876 asdadad30 asasda36" | perl -pe 's/\D+//g'
```

prints:

```
628178763036
```

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that you need two operations:

1. Remove everything that is neither a blank nor a digit:

   ```
   s/[^ \d]//g;
   ```
2. Remove all extra blanks:

   ```
   s/  +/ /g;
   ```

   If you need to remove leading and trailing blanks too:

   ```
   s/^ //;
   s/ $//;
   ```

   (after the replace multiple blanks with a single blank).

You can use `\s` to represent more space-like characters than just a blank.

Comment: This is cool for retaining the spaces between digits but I'm pretty sure the OP wants to remove the spaces between the digits; see his desired output of `628178763036`. He's also saying he wants to select the spaces for removal.

Comment: @StigBrautaset: It depends on your interpretation of the last comments in the question, about `62(select the space here)81`.  I interpreted that to mean 'keep the space between the digits'; if the OP has a different meaning for that, then you'd have to adapt my regex.  Indeed, you can then use `s/[^\d]+//g;` to do the job in a single regex.

Comment: The subject of the question is "regex remove space"... :-)

Comment: @StigBrautaset — OK: we're going to have to agree to differ until the question is clarified.  I note that `[^\d]+` is equivalent to `\D+`, so my alternative regex could be just `s/\D+//g`.  The original regex with its `\s` in the middle of the character class would match the spaces; it only runs into issues because of the `^` anchor at the start.  Otherwise, it would remove garbage, including spaces, everywhere.

Comment: I agree the question could be clearer, and have asked for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

If you make a replace you can reconstruct the phone number with the space between numbers:

```
search:  \D*(\d+)\D*?(\s?)
replace: $1$2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a look-behind and a look-ahead to assert that digits must precede/follow the space(s):

```
(?<=\d) +(?=\d)
```

The entire regex matches the spaces, so no need to reference groups in your replacement, just replace with a blank.