# How to trim whitespaces inside regex replacement string

Tags: c#, regex, c#-4.0

I have a regex match string as;

```
    public static string RegExMatchString = "(?<NVE>.{20})(?<SN>.{20})(?<REGION>.{4})(?<YY>\\d{4})(?<Mo" +
    "n>\\d{2})(?<DD>\\d{1,2})(?<HH>\\d{2})(?<Min>\\d{2})(?<SS>\\d" +
    "{2}).{6}(?<USER>.{10})(?<SCANTYPE>.{2})(?<IN>.{4})(?<OU" +
    "T>.{4})(?<DISPO>.{2})(?<ROUTE>.{7})(?<LP>.{16})(?<POOL>.{3})" +
    "(?<CONT>.{9})(?<REGION_L>.{18})(?<CAT>.{2})";
```

And I'm replacing it as

```
    public string RegExReplacementString = "LogBarcodeID ( \"${NVE}\", ID2: \"${SN}\", Scanner: \"${USER}" +
    "\", AreaName: \"${REGION_L}${CAT}${SCANTYPE}\", TimeStamp: \"${YY}/${Mon}/${D" +
    "D} ${HH}:${Min}:${SS} \") ";
```

I need to remove all trailing and preceding whitespaces from these three variable;

```
${REGION_L} 
${CAT} 
${SCANTYPE}
```

How should I change RegExReplacementString  (or maybe RegExMatchString)  so that this can be achieved?

Sample input is:

```
    0034025876080795786104041811071         135 20150304111404      DFRANZ    61    9990020569910                 DA ST6007    135              F
```

Currently I'm getting related part as
`AreaName: "135 F61"` however I need to get AreaName: "135F61"

**EDIT:**
I'm reading regex match string from text file. And initing regex ;

```
RegExMatchString = File.ReadAllText(regexMatchStringPath);
regex = new Regex( RegExMatchString ,
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant
    | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.Compiled
    );
string replaced = regex.Replace("0034025876080795786104041811071         135 20150304111404      DFRANZ    61    9990020569910                 DA ST6007    135              F", RegExReplacementString);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267488/regex-remove-space try this

Comment: @Harry he wants to select spaces as well, but I need to trim spaces for above three  variables

Comment: Why dont you try a String.Replace?

Comment: Because replacement string is coming from a conf file. So I need to do it inside replacement string or regex.

Comment: Your `RegExReplacementString` is not a valid string in C#. Moreover, you are not showing how you create a regex object, currently, your regex string is incorrect (you must double `\`s). Please adjust your question so that we could test your code and come up with answers.

Comment: @stribizhev I'm reading regex from text file. I'm editing my question which shows initing of regex as well

Comment: Could you please also provide the `RegExReplacementString` as a single string that can be tested with? The rest looks fine.

Comment: I edited both strings as chsarp strings you should be able to just copy and paste it directly.

Answer (score 0):

I think the fixed length info of each field would be useful to solve the problem here.

use a regex like : `"^(.{20})(.{10})(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})$"` to isolate each field.

This is for an example with 5 fields that you know are of

Length 20, Length 10, Length 2, Length 2, Length 2.

then use some LINQ and C# to get a list of (trimmed) fields.

Example :

```
var testRegex = "^(.{20})(.{10})(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})$";
var testData = "Field of length 20  FieldLen10123456";
var fields = Regex.Match(testData, testRegex).Groups.Cast<Group>().Skip(1).Select(i => i.Value.Trim());
```

Comment: I need to make it inside match or replacement string because they are being read from a configuration file. So I can't use code side for trimming.

Comment: I don't understand, even if you read the input data and the regex pattern from files, you can do c# processing?