# dart regex remove space phone

Tags: regex, dart, flutter

I tried all this regex solution but no match [REGEX Remove Space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267488/regex-remove-space)

I work with dart and flutter and I tried to capture only digit of this type of string :

case 1

```
     aaaaaaaaa 06 12 34 56 78  aaaaaa
```

case 2

```
    aaaaaaaa 0612345678 aaaaaa
```

case 3

```
   aaaaaa +336 12 34 56 78 aaaaa
```

I search to have only 0612345678 with no space and no +33. Just 10 digit in se case of +33 I need to replace +33 by 0

currently I have this code \D*(\d+)\D*? who run with the case 2

Comment: Why did you choose to try `\D*(\d+)\D*?`? It does not match digits separated with spaces. What is the rule for the pattern? The first digit/space chunk in the string?

Comment: sorry (\d+) is sufficient currently it match with   aaaaaaaa 0612345678 aaaaaa   the result is 0612345678. but this code no working if there is space between digit like 06 12 34 56 78

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may match and capture an optional `+33` and then a digit followed with spaces or digits, and then check if Group 1 matched and then build the result accordingly.

Here is an example solution (tested):

```
var strs = ['aaaaaaaaa 06 12 34 56 78  aaaaaa', 'aaaaaaaa 0612345678 aaaaaa', 'aaaaaa +336 12 34 56 78 aaaaa', 'more +33 6 12 34 56 78'];
  for (int i = 0; i < strs.length; i++) {
    var rx = new RegExp(r"(?:^|\D)(\+33)?\s*(\d[\d ]*)(?!\d)");
    var match = rx.firstMatch(strs[i]);
    var result = "";
    if (match != null) {
      if (match.group(1) != null) {
        result = "0" + match.group(2).replaceAll(" ", "");
      } else {
        result = match.group(2).replaceAll(" ", "");
      }
      print(result);
  }
}
```

Returns 3 `0612345678` strings in the output.

The pattern is

```
(?:^|\D)(\+33)?\s*(\d[\d ]*)(?!\d)
```

See [its demo here](https://regex101.com/r/chpB6P/3).

- `(?:^|\D)` - start of string or any char other than a digit
- `(\+33)?` - Group 1 that captures `+33` 1 or 0 times
- `\s*` - any 0+ whitespaces
- `(\d[\d ]*)` - Group 2: a digit followed with spaces or/and digits
- `(?!\d)` - no digit immediately to the right is allowed.

Spaces are removed from Group 2 with a `match.group(2).replaceAll(" ", "")` since one can't match discontinuous strings within one match operation.

Comment: sorry I have an other case ... with +33 6 12 34 56 78 it return 33612345678

Comment: it's ok with (r"(?:^|\D)(\+33)?\s?(\d[\d ]*)(?!\d)")

Comment: @QuentinGuichot Right, you may also use `\s*` to match 0 or more whitespaces, rather than `\s?` that matches 1 or 0 whitespaces. I updated the answer to account for that scenario as well.